# how send a email with OAuth and Outlook using python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Hi I´m new trying to get data from Apis:

Im trying to send an email from a Qt app getting the email and password from a text_edit my problem is when im trying to get the api auth from microsoft(Azure)

```
from urllib.parse import quote, urlencode
import base64
import json
import time

# Client ID and secret
client_id = 'UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU'
client_secret = ' PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP'

# Constant strings for OAuth2 flow
# The OAuth authority
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'

# The authorize URL that initiates the OAuth2 client credential flow for admin consent
authorize_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?{0}')

# The token issuing endpoint
token_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token')

# The scopes required by the app
scopes = [ 'Mail.Read',
        'Mail.Send' ]

def get_signin_url(redirect_uri):
# Build the query parameters for the signin url
params = { 'client_id': client_id,
         'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
         'response_type': 'code',
         'scope': ' '.join(str(i) for i in scopes)
        }

signin_url = authorize_url.format(urlencode(params))

return signin_url
```

This code is to generate the url to login that is called by:

```
def Message_Send():

   Sign  = QS.get_signin_url('Directorio://auth')
   data={
    'loginfmt':'XXXXXXXXX',
    'passwd':'YYYYYYYYY'
    }
    requ = requests.Session()

    geto=requ.post(Sign,)
```

But when i try to get  a json from geto app crashes and if I use geto.text show me a kind of HTML page without body

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
```

This is the error when use json
I get status code 200
the app UI is made by pyqt

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Qt so the tag is unnecessary and consequently I have removed it. Read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Comment: I see a Qt method that is Qt.QOAuth2_AuthCodeFLow (Something like that) and this are one of the methods that do something but have the same kind of error

Comment: In the code you provide I don't see anything of Qt so the use of Qt is irrelevant, imagine if each user has to place the tags of the libraries used by his project: we would lack space. In conclusion: That your project uses Qt does not imply that a problem within your project depends on Qt